# XPages: context.getUser().getRoles() working sporadically

Tags: xpages

This is weird.

I've logged in here as Admin Mustermann, but when I try to determine the user's roles, I get nothing:

```
current user:
<xp:text
    escape="true"
    id="computedField4"
    value="#{javascript:context.getUser()}">
</xp:text>
roles:
    <xp:text
    escape="true"
    id="computedField5"
    value="#{javascript:context.getUser().getRoles()}">
</xp:text>
```

[image]

And if I open my XPages Debug Toolbar, it tells me I'm Anonymous.

[image]

This is my ACL which confirms Admin Mustermann should have at least three roles:

[image]

I'm stumped.

Comment: You have no roles because you are Anonymous. You should figure out why, and your roles will show up. What is strange is that your app is showing that you are logged in. What is the code there?

Comment: the code to display the current user is the ssjs that I posted above. The code above is an Application Layout with a userTreeNode and a loginTreeNode

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd prefer to use `database.queryAccessRoles(session.getEffectiveUserName())` instead of using the context.

I created a bean for getting a lot of ACL and user informations as a snippet: http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=sysinfouser-acl-info-custom-control-java-bean

Comment: yeah that works. Any idea why the XPages toolbar is not displaying correctly? Do I need to refresh something?

Comment: No idea, maybe ask Mark Leusink how it works - or have a look in the sources how it's done. Maybe it's using the context, too.

Comment: Great tip Oliver!  Think I will also start using this instead from now on.

Comment: Andrew, could you then please accept this answer if it works for you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Oddly, @UserRoles is more reliable. Try using this instead:

```
roles:
    <xp:text
    escape="true"
    id="computedField5"
    value="#{javascript:session.evaluate("@UserRoles");}">
</xp:text>
```

We had a problem with context.getUser().getRoles() failing when using XPages in the Notes Client on local when not disconnected. You can reconfigure your location document in some manner to avoid this, but I never figured that one out. Using the old formula language stuff was suggested during a PMR and it works even if the coinfiguration is, like mine, wrong.