# Forcing Users to Log on for a particular XPage: Is the <xp:aclEntry> tag flaky?

Tags: xpages

I have a 'Registration' XPage for which I want the end-user to be logged in. Normal users can browse the database, but when they need to register, then I want them to register.

I have been using the the xp:aclEntry tag to control this

```
<xp:this.acl>
    <xp:acl>
        <xp:this.entries>
            <xp:aclEntry
                type="ROLE"
                loaded="true"
                right="EDITOR">
                <xp:this.name><![CDATA[[CreateAnmeldung]]]></xp:this.name>
            </xp:aclEntry>
        </xp:this.entries>
    </xp:acl>
</xp:this.acl>
```

but now I'm getting this

[image]

Even though I would argue that the user has that role:

[image]

[image]

Oliver Busse suggested in an earlier question of mine to avoid the aclEntry tag and instead do some code in the beforePageLoad event. Is this correct best practice?

Or, have I missed something?

Comment: I am a little unclear.  Do you have code to redirect to your custom login page when the user tries to access the Registration Page?

Comment: I mean something like:  if (context.getUser().getCommonName() == "Anonymous"){
  sessionScope.put("entryPage",context.getUrl().getPath() + context.getUrl().getQueryString())
  context.redirectToPage("~~~~~~~~/login.xsp");
 }  Except you don't check for Anonymous, you check for something else.  This is in the beforePageLoad like Oliver suggested

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. Yes, I also agree with Oliver. Will put in an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrew,

Best practice is always up for debate, but I agree with Oliver that you should check in your `beforePageLoad` and redirect in that manner.  I have never used the `<xp:aclEntry>` myself, so I can't directly tell you whether it is flakey.

In this example, I check for Anonymous, but it sounds like your check will be different.  If using in this manner then you MUST allow public access on the XPage. (I am adding this because it is often missed)

```
//Check Access level, if Anonymous, redirect them to login page.
if (context.getUser().getCommonName() == "Anonymous"){
    context.redirectToPage("/~~~/~~~.nsf/login.xsp");
}
```

[image: Must allow this on each XPage to redirect properly]

---

In addition, please see Oliver's answer on a better way to determine the access level: [XPages: context.getUser().getRoles() working sporadically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191459/xpages-context-getuser-getroles-working-sporadically/30191842#30191842)

I haven't used this yet, and had no problems using the code above, but remembered that this came up recently. **Edit**: Just saw this was *your* question, so safe to say you know about it :), but leaving for posterity.

Comment: lol, yes it was my question too. I'm bombarding SO right now with questions.

Comment: the follow-up question would be: what would you recommend as a login.xsp? Here again there seems to be many different approaches - there are three or four in openntf. Do you know of a convenient one I could just copy?

Comment: Ours is a derivitive of an openNTF project...will try to figure out which one and edit my answer.  I copied from an another internal project, that existed before I joined this company.

Comment: plus, are you hard-coding the nsf name? Shouldn't I use something like context.getUrl().getPath()?

Comment: If I remember correctly, I had problem using that. It didn't always work consistently.

Comment: but I see the advantage of having one's own login page. It makes it easy to redirect to 'the last page'. But man, eh, it seems that everywhere I need to build some scaffolding which I had assumed was there out of the box. sigh.

Comment: No, custom login pages are not out of the box.  Glad that we have openNTF

Comment: Andrew, I *think* that we are using a derivitive of the Steve Castledine project. There are new ones to choose from as well on openNTF.  Mark Leusink's one looks pretty cool.

Comment: For an example with its own login XPage, you may want to look at the [XControls project on GitHub](https://github.com/teamstudio/xcontrols-domino/blob/master/sampler-app/CustomControls/UnpBootResources.xsp#L51-L55). They have a [common header CC](https://github.com/teamstudio/xcontrols-domino/blob/master/sampler-app/CustomControls/commonheader.xsp#L10) that contains another bit for an _afterPageLoad_ event which checks for and redirects to a login page accordingly.